# Instance member in Parallel.Foreach loop vs. thread-safety

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, thread-safety, locking

I would have the questions below, that are somehow linked to each other and relevant to the code below (simplified - see comments):

```
public class DataProcessor
{
    private DataUpdater dataUpdater = new DataUpdater(someConnection);

    public void Process()
    {
        Parallel.ForEach(itemCollection, (item, loopState) =>
        {
            ProcessItem(item);
            // Q1. is this thread safe? (as I understand, same DataUpdater instance for all threads)
            // Q4. should a new DataUpdater be created here and passed to ProcessItem as parameter instead?

            // (commented as not relevant to question)
            // if (mustStop()) 
            // {
            //     loopState.Break();
            // }
        });

    }

    private void ProcessItem(Item item)
    {
        // some processing...

        dataUpdater.Update(item); // Q2. should I lock here if 1. is not thread-safe?
    }
}

public class DataUpdater // Q3. could/should this be made a static helper class?
{
    private IDatabaseConnection databaseConnection;

    public DataUpdater(IDatabaseConnection databaseConnection)
    {
        this.databaseConnection = databaseConnection;
    }

    public void Update(item)
    {
        using (var ctx = new DataContext(databaseConnection.ConnectionString))
        {
            // Linq2Sql
            ctx.Item.InsertOnSubmit(item);
            ctx.SubmitChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

In the code above, the data processor uses a `Parallel.Foreach` loop in order to speed up some heavy processing in the `ProcessItem` method (not relevant to the question). After processing, the item is updated in the database via the DataUpdater class.

Questions are:

1. when using a database updater as instance member of `DataProcessor`, is the `ProcessItem` call thread-safe?
2. if not, does adding a `lock(obj)` around the call to `dataUpdater.Update` in the `ProcessItem` method solve the thread-safety issue, provided that the rest of the processing in that method does not need to be thread-safe?
3. should class `DataUpdater` (and its methods) be made static instead? Would this remove the thread-safety issue?
4. should a new instance of `DataUpdater` be created in the loop and passed as parameter to `ProcessItem` instead?

**edit**

Added code to `Update` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when using a database updater as instance member of DataProcessor, is the ProcessItem call thread-safe?

Can't say for sure because you did not show us exactly what `Update()` does nor if `IDatabaseConnection`'s methods are safe to call on multiple threads at the same time, however it is most likely not thread safe.

> if not, does adding a lock(obj) around the call to dataUpdater.Update in the ProcessItem method solve the thread-safety issue, provided that the rest of the processing in that method does not need to be thread-safe?

Potentially that could make it thread safe, but you need to make sure the `IDatabaseConnection` is either thread safe or not used concurrently anywhere else in the program outside of this loop while the loop is running.

> should class DataUpdater (and its methods) be made static instead? Would this remove the thread-safety issue?

No, making something static does not magically make something thread safe, it is the code inside the method that makes it safe, if it is static or not has no effect.

> should a new instance of DataUpdater be created in the loop and passed as parameter to ProcessItem instead?

Yes and no, `Parallel.ForEach` [has overloads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991486(v=vs.110).aspx) that have special delegates that happen at the start and end of each thread which crates a thread local object and that object gets reused within the thread each call. You should be creating the new updater there.

In the below example I have made some small assumptions, `someConnection` is not thread safe but provides a `.Clone()` method that creates a new connection that can be used concurrently with the old connection. Also I assumed there is a `.Close()` method on `DataUpdater` that can be called to close the connection that was passed in.

```
public void Process()
{
    Parallel.ForEach(itemCollection,
        //This is called at the creation of a thread, may be called on many threads at once.
        () =>  
        {
            lock(someConnection)
            {
                var newConnection = someConnection.Clone();
                return new DataUpdater(newConnection)
            }
        };
        (item, loopState, dataUpdater) => //dataUpdater is the thread local copy
        {
            ProcessItem(item, dataUpdater);

            // (commented as not relevant to question)
            // if (mustStop()) 
            // {
            //     loopState.Break();
            // }

            //This will get passed in to the next item or the cleanup method.
            return dataUpdater;
         }
        //This is called at the end of a thread after it has finished processing items.
        , (dataUpdater) => dataUpdater.Close() 
        );
}

private void ProcessItem(Item item, DataUpdater dataUpdater)
{
    // some processing...

    dataUpdater.Update(item);
}
```

---

**APPENDIX A:**

A simplified example of what ForEach is doing internally.

```
public static ParallelLoopResult ForEach<TSource, TLocal>(IEnumerable<TSource> source, 
                       Func<TLocal> localInit,
                       Func<TSource, ParallelLoopState, TLocal, TLocal> body,
                       Action<TLocal> localFinally)
{
    ParallelLoopState[] loopStates;
    IEnumerable<TSource>[] jobBatches;
    // (SNIP)
    Task.Run(() => WorkerThread(jobBatchs[0], localInit, body, localFinally, loopStates[0]))
    Task.Run(() => WorkerThread(jobBatchs[1], localInit, body, localFinally, loopStates[1]))
    // (SNIP)
}

private static void WorkerThread<TSource, TLocal>(IEnumerable<TSource> jobBatch,
                       Func<TLocal> localInit,
                       Func<TSource, ParallelLoopState, TLocal, TLocal> body,
                       Action<TLocal> localFinally,
                       ParallelLoopState loopState)
{
    TLocal localData = localInit();
    foreach(TSource data in jobBatch)
    {
        if(loopState.ShouldExitCurrentIteration)
            break;
        localData = body(data, loopState, localData);
    }
    localFinally(localData);
}
```

Comment: I agree: you're better off creating a new connection for each item. This does take a bit more memory, but will make it go faster. If you use only one connection and lock, then only one update to the database can be processed at a time, which will slow down the loop.

Comment: @GabrielLuci It depends on the relative time of processing vs saving to the database. If it takes 4-8 seconds to do the `// some processing...` section and 75ms to do `dataUpdater.Update(item);` then a lock will likely not be even noticed as there will likely be low contention for the lock.

Comment: Agreed. I only chimed in because I've been this situation before. I used to try my best not to create new instances of objects, and instead reuse one instance. More often than not it either doesn't work at all, or creates some crazy issues when multiple threads use it. Using a new object each time doesn't add any noticeable overhead.

Comment: @Scott - Thanks for the answers. I added the code to Update method. IDatabaseConnection provides a connection string that I use, that's why did not care about thread safety. I don't understand in your code the localInit method, I mean how does the main loop know that the returned DataUpdater to be used it the one returned by the localInit loop? That sure does seem a bit magical to me as I can't see the DataUpdater being stored anywhere (explicitely at least)... sorry I'm still not comfortable with threading yet. Also if I understand well there is 1 updater per thread right?

Comment: @supafly `LocalInit`'s signature is `DataUpdater localInit()` so the created uploader is returned through the return method. Then on your parrallel function your old signature was `void body(Item item, ParallelLoopState loopState)` the new signature for my version is `DataUpdater body(Item item, ParallelLoopState loopState, DataUpdater dataUpdater)` so the `dataUpdater` is passed in to the function then it is returned at the end of the function. See the Appendix A I added to my answer.

Comment: The reason `body` both accepts a `TLocal` and returns a `TLocal` is in case the type if `TLocal` is a struct and the value is changed inside of `body`. For example if `TLocal` was a `int` representing some kind of running total you could have, localInit would be `() => 0`, body would be `(data, loopState, total) => { total += data.CalculateTotal(); return total; }`, and in the local finally you would do `(total) => { lock(_lockObj) { grandTotal += total; } }` where `grandTotal` is a `int` declared outside of the `Parallel.ForEach`.